# How Do I Invoke The Following Makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

I'm trying to submit code to this website but am told that g++ is being invoked with the following:

```
g++ -static -fno-strict-aliasing -DONLINE_JUDGE -lm -s 
    -x c++ -Wl,--stack=67108864 -O2 -o %1.exe %1
```

I understand that this can be invoked in the command line or added in as a line in a Makefile but I don't know where I am supposed to put my target's filename, say *help-me.cpp*

Comment: The guide for C/C++ solution submissions is here:
http://acm.timus.ru/help.aspx?topic=cpp

Comment: Think on that happens if the input arguments are `foo bar`.

Comment: Also it is not specified whether or not input is on the command line or intended to be read in from stdin. What does your program do if there are no command line arguments?

Comment: It doesn't matter if there are no command line arguments; I can confirm this via an example from the website.

Comment: raw command line would be `g++ -static -fno-strict-aliasing -DONLINE_JUDGE -lm -s -x c++ -Wl,--stack=67108864 -O2 -o help-me.exe help-me.cpp`

Comment: The code you had up in the original text of the question would almost certainly crash without command line arguments. if there is no `argv[1]` specified and you try to use it, it's a bad scene.

Comment: I get the following returned to me from the terminal: /usr/bin/ld:unrecognized option '--stack=67108864'

Comment: Ah, yeah, it would crash. My mistake :/ Thank you

Comment: Can't help you with that one. Check your g++ version `g++ -v` on the command line. Personally I'd leave it out. You don't need much stack for this.

Comment: You should put your response(s) as a reply so I can mark it as a solution.

Also, why I wrote the code that way (as you originally saw) is because of the way the website displayed input/output. Have a lookie here, please:
http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1000

To me, that implies using argv[1] + argv[2]. The website uses this first problem to give an example solution where it simply just does:

int a, b;
std::cin >> a >> b; 

Which could also have crashing consequences if the user typed in the non-integer values. So, long story short, the program checking for solutions doesn't care